# In Appian, i have created a process model. In that approve, reject, and screening action is involved

Tags: error-handling, nodes, appian, processmodel, itaskitem

In Appian, i have created a process model. In that approve, reject, and screening action is involved.
I am taking decision for each action. If decision is true for any of the action i am finishing the process. Or else it will return back to main form.
And also i want to print the appropriate error there and then back to main form. But i am not getting the error. And it is finishing the process itself.

I am expecting to print error and and it should return to main form. But because screening node and approve node is crossing each other for that reason only i think i am not getting proper results.

How can i implement that?